# NameError: uninitialized constant Object::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, irb, nameerror

I searched the other posts that had this issue and could not find one that fixed my particular issue. My irb is going crazy. I am trying to change user roles in my database but I can't even get to my users!

```
irb(main):001:0> User.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::User
        from (irb):1
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

It was working fine, stopped working, was fine, and now stopped again. I have a User model and users added. I cannot pinpoint the issue. Let me know what code you need to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should run

```
ruby script/console # Rails < 3
```

or

```
rails c  # Rails 3.x
```

But not (I believe you've just run this)

```
irb
```

Comment: You mean console, not server.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks a lot. What a stupid mistake I made. I was told that you can go with either one and it will take you to the same place. Not true.

Comment: or in my case if you want to start it in production mode you can run $rails c production

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you're actually using the `rails console` command rather than just running `irb` in your project folder.

Comment: Is there a good reason why to use rails console rather then irb? 
Is it possible to access project model Object via irb? So far I'm getting this "NameError: uninitialized constant ...".

Comment: `irb` won't load your Rails environment at all, you have to use the rails console for that.